# Requesting android permissions only once

Tags: android, dynamic, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

When we ask permission from the user on his phone, is there a way we can inform the OS not to ask this permission again? No matter what the user's response is.

Answer (score 3):

If the program does not "desperately" require the permission, you can use SharedPreferences and store a variable called firstTime withe boolean value of true. 
Then check in the onCreate method for that variable. if it is true, ask the permission then set the value to false and save it. Then when the user will rerun the application, it won't be the "FirstTime" so he won't be prompted with the permission.

```
 SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("PACKAGE.NAME",MODE_PRIVATE);
 Boolean firstTime = pref.getBoolean("firstTime",true);
 if(firstTime){
 //Ask for permissions here
 pref.edit().putBoolean("firstTime",false).apply();
 }
```

Comment: I had this idea, but since the user can inform OS by checking the checkbox in the dialogue, I was wondering if there is any option to pass that parameter programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

No, sorry. You would need to keep track of whether you asked the user for permissions, then use that information to determine whether or not to ask in the future.

Comment: Any sources? So that I can clearly discard this idea and start workarounds.

Comment: @arunwithasmile: "Any sources?" -- I cannot show you documentation about something that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

When you ask the permission in any way like in the following, in the dialog that would be open to ask for permission there is a check box that by checking it, OS would not ask you for that permission any more:

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, RC_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
 }
```